# How do I create an async overload of an existing synchronous method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have several libraries that currently don't support async/await and I'm trying to update them. For methods that can call existing async code (such as using `File.ReadAllLinesAsync` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`) creating an async overload is pretty easy. However, for methods that don't call other code that has asynchronous capabilities, the overload is not so easy.

As an example, Let's say I have a method as follows:

```csharp
public ResultType DoLotsOfStuff(string p1, string p2)
{
   ResultType result = new ResultType();
   // Do Lots of stuff here.
   // update result

   return result;
}
```

I would like to create an async overload of this method, but don't want to duplicate all the code within it. So the method starts off simply:

```
public Task<ResultType> DoLotsOfStuffAsync(string p1, string p2)
```

The question becomes what do I do inside the new overload to call the original method?

I've seen several possible answers, but not sure if any of them are good ones, nor which is the best under what circumstances. So far, I've seen these:

Method 1: Use `Task.Yield`

```
public Task<ResultType> DoLotsOfStuffAsync(string p1, string p2)
{
   Task.Yield();
   return DoLotsOfStuff(p1, p2);
}
```

Method 2: Use `Task.Run`

```
public Task<ResultType> DoLotsOfStuffAsync(string p1, string p2)
{
   return await Task.Run(() => DoLotsOfStuff(p1, p2));
}
```

Method 3: Use `Task.FromResult`

```
public Task<ResultType> DoLotsOfStuffAsync(string p1, string p2)
{
   ResultType result = DoLotsOfStuff(p1, p2);
   return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

All three of those compile fine, so I'm not sure which to use. Are they equivalent? If not, what are the ramifications of using each?

As a bit of background, the libraries may be used in a variety of applications including ASP.Net Core web apps, .Net Core Console Apps, and possible .Net Core UI apps. I've done several hours of internet searching and found all of those methods, just nothing on which to use when.

Thanks!

Comment: [Task.Run Etiquette](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)

Comment: If it matters, Microsoft's implementation of `ReadAllLinesAsync` is separate from the `ReadAllLines`  Similar in structure but using async methods.

Comment: Important reading: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: If you have naturally-asynchronous methods (usually I/O work). then expose those as asynchronous APIs. If you have naturally-synchronous methods (usually CPU work), then expose those as synchronous APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of those methods are fake asynchrony. If you are not going to provide an actually asynchronous implementation (by awaiting naturally/actually asynchronous operations like IO), then don't provide these overloads at all.

I highly recommend reading [Task.Run Etiquette](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) which Alexander Petrov already commented.

Comment: I finally had time to go and read the article. Thank you, and thanks to Alexander Petrov as well!

Comment: @BardMorgan If you haven't, make sure to also read all the sub-articles under the blue "Want a more detailed discussion? Read .." sections.